# mongoDB Aggregate please.... list Duplicate Total

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

code currently in use

```
db.events.aggregate([
      { '$match':
          { thingId: 'node_0002',
            eventState: 'test',
            deviceId: {'$in': ['ARCT-1', 'ARCT-2', 'ARSS-1', 'ARSS-2', 'ARSW-1', 'ARCO-1']},
            collectTimeText: {'$gte': '2022-04-01T00:00:00+09:00', '$lte': '2022-04-19T23:59:59+09:00' }}},
      { '$group': {
          _id: {'$dateFromString': { dateString: { '$substr': [ '$collectTimeText', 0, 10 ] }}
          },
          list: { '$addToSet': {'deviceId':'$deviceId'} }},
      },
      {'$unwind':'$list'},
      { '$group': {
          _id: {'$dateToString': {'format': "%Y-%m",  date: "$_id"}
          },
          list: { '$push': '$list' }},
      },
      {'$sort': { _id: 1 } }], {})
```

result of using the code

```
{ _id: '2022-04',
  list: 
   [ { deviceId: 'ARCT-2' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCT-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSW-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCO-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-2' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCT-2' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCT-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSW-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCO-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-2' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCT-2' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCT-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSW-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARCO-1' },
     { deviceId: 'ARSS-2' } ] }
```

I want an output like the code below. Help

```
{ _id: '2022-04',
  list: 
   { 'ARCO-1': 3,
     'ARCT-1': 3,
     'ARSS-1': 3,
     'ARCT-2': 3,
     'ARSS-2': 3,
     'ARSW-1': 3 } }
```

This is the code for generating statistics.

How do I get the results I want?

Did I write the code wrong in the first place?

When I added $project , I got the following result. How to check the count

```
db.events.aggregate([
      { '$match':
          { thingId: 'node_0002',
            eventState: 'test',
            deviceId: {'$in': ['ARCT-1', 'ARCT-2', 'ARSS-1', 'ARSS-2', 'ARSW-1', 'ARCO-1']},
            collectTimeText: {'$gte': '2022-04-01T00:00:00+09:00', '$lte': '2022-04-19T23:59:59+09:00' }}},
      { '$group': {
          _id: {'$dateFromString': { dateString: { '$substr': [ '$collectTimeText', 0, 10 ] }}
          },
          list: { '$addToSet': {'deviceId':'$deviceId'} }},
      },
      {'$unwind':'$list'},
      { '$group': {
          _id: {'$dateToString': {'format': "%Y-%m",  date: "$_id"}
          },
          list: { '$push': '$list' }},
      },
    {'$project':{
        'list':{
          '$arrayToObject':{
            '$map': {
              'input': '$list',
              'as': 'el',
              'in': {
                'k': '$$el.deviceId',
                'v': {'$sum':1}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }},
    {'$sort': { _id: 1 } }], {})
```

Below is the result of adding $project.

```
{ _id: '2022-04',
  list: 
   { 'ARCO-1': 1,
     'ARCT-1': 1,
     'ARSS-1': 1,
     'ARCT-2': 1,
     'ARSS-2': 1,
     'ARSW-1': 1 } }
```

I don't know what to do.... It seems like I'm almost there, but I don't know...

Maybe not all...?

Comment: You should not store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Better store proper `Date` objects. Your query may fail when you work with different time zones, e.g. when using Daylight-Saving-Times. Instead of `_id: {'$dateToString': {'format': "%Y-%m",  date: "$_id"}` you can also use `_id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$collectDate", unit: "month", timezone: "+09:00" } }`

Answer (score 1):

`$group` twice and then `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: "$date",
        deviceId: "$deviceId"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.date",
      list: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.deviceId",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      list: {
        $arrayToObject: "$list"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ciLyDEmzCrK)